# Variational form of boundary value problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Given Dirichlet boundary value problem

$$
\begin{array}[t]{rcl}
-\Delta u&=f &\text{ in }\Omega\\
u&=0 &\text{ on }\partial\Omega,
\end{array}
$$

we can use Green's theorem and transform it into variational form:

$$l(v):=\int_\Omega fv\text{ dx}=\int_\Omega -\Delta u f\text{ dx}=\int_\Omega \nabla u\cdot\nabla v \text{ dx}=: a(u,v),$$

so that the problem boils down to find $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ (Sobolev space) such that:

$$a(u,v)=l(v) \,\,\,\,\forall v \in H^1(\Omega).$$

But now I am given a task that goes in opposite direction:

Which boundary value problem is solved by the problem in variational form:

$$
\begin{array}[t]{rcl}
a(u,v)&=&\int_0^1 x^2u'(x)v'(x)\text{ dx}\\
l(v)&=&\int_0^1 v(x)\text{ dx}.
\end{array}$$

So we got different $a$ with $x^2$ on the right hand side and this must be some another common PDE, and I can't see which.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What about $(x^2 u')' = 1$ with $u(0) = u(1) = 0$?

Comment: Yes it will do, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, if you plug in test function you fine out that your variational formulation is equivalent to 
$$x^2u''+2xu'= (x^2u')' = 1, ~~~in ~~~~(0,1)~~~~and ~~~~ u(0)=u(1)=0. $$